# How to import the AltBeacon library inside my Android Studio 1.0 empty project

Tags: android

I have been trying to use the AltBeacon Monitoring Example Code to monitor my Kontakt.io beacon as described http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html here.

I have donwloaded the Library with .aar extension dedicated to Android Studio in my PC but could not find the way to import it to my Android studio?

I staredt with Android studio few month agao and importing external Library have never done it before.

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html - doesn't it answer your quiestion?

Comment: this is what I try to follow but really fuzzy on how to add the folder

Comment: Right click->new->directory or copy paste doesn't work?

Comment: @Divers, yes it works now but my mistake was that I did not know from where to create the folder. You must be in the Poject View and not Android View as I was in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First

Please go to the original project page: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library and http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html.

### Second

From the link you provided, add this to your `build.gradle` like it tells you too:

**Step 1. Get the Library and Copy it to Your Project**

Download the AAR file

Create a /libs directory inside your project and copy the AAR file there.

**Step 2. Configure your app's build.gradle File**

add a "flatDir" entry to your repositories like so:

```
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
     }
   }
```

add the library AAR as a dependency like so:

```
   dependencies {
     compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+@aar'
   }
```

Source: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html

Comment: this is what I have done, my initila question was how to import the Library in the project itself. I finally dsicover it. I need first to chnage the view on top nav bar of android studio to "Project" instead of "Android", then from here I manage to create simple lib folder. Then in repository of build .Gradle I cannot leav the jCenter() I need to replace all by MavenCtral instead of JCenter

Comment: Why would you want to add the entire project to your project?

Comment: I did not add the whole project, I just copy the .aar file

Comment: Read: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html. It explains how to download and copy the aar to your project.

Comment: What? That is what I was doing. Read the link. All you did was follow the steps in the link I gave you.

Comment: was not clear enough when you have never play with android studio. Espceially teh steps where i need to switch to project view

Comment: All you had to do was copy and paste. I now copied and pasted their exact instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete flow of steps :

1 - be sure to be in the Project view a follwoing picture shows

[image]

2 -Right click the root project and select New->Directory

3 - Name the directory "Libs"

4 - Copy the .aar Library reference in the directory

5 - Open the Buld.gradle from the App and change it as follow :

[image]